# Suppose a function is expressed by: $f(x)=f(x+1) - f(x-1)$ and $f(16)=20 , f(20)=16$ What is $f(20162016)$?

Tags: functions, recreational-mathematics

**Math quiz bee question**

> Suppose a function is expressed by:
>   $$f(x)=f(x+1) + f(x-1)$$
>   and
>   $$f(16)=20 , f(20)=16.$$
>   What is $f(20162016)$?

---

**Attempt at solution:**
$f(17)+f(15)=20$
$f(21)+f(19)=16$
And if I continue it, I can get the values of $f(21)$ and the other integers near it, but how can I get to the value of $f(20162016)$?

This question was from a recent national quiz bee in my place, it is only for $30$ seconds.

The correct answer that they said was $-36$.

Edit 1: As some pointed out, I think I remembered it wrong and the question was:
$$f(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-1)$$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Should the main equation be $f(x+1)=f(x)-f(x-1)$?

Comment: Are you sure it has a time limit of 30 seconds ? That is crazy.

Comment: Is this a quiz for Math PhDs or graduate school students ?

Comment: @user230452 It's for undergraduate engineering students, it has a time limit of 30 seconds but we can answer while the question is being read, to be safe I think we had a minute more or less to answer it.

Comment: @probablyme thanks for the formatting

Answer (score 5):

For the originally posted question, $f(x)=f(x+1)-f(x-1)$

Rearranging, we have the recurrence relation $f(x+1)=f(x)+f(x-1)$

Looking at its characteristic polynomial, it is of the form $\lambda^2=\lambda+1$

Solving for $\lambda$, we get $\lambda = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ as the solutions.  This implies that $f(x)$ will be of the form:

$$f(x)=\alpha\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^x + \beta\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^x$$

for some values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be determined based on our initial conditions.

Using $f(16)=20$ and $f(20)=16$, we can create a system of two equations with two unknowns.

$\begin{cases}20 = \alpha (\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{16}+\beta (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{16} = \alpha(\frac{2207+987\sqrt{5}}{2}) + \beta(\frac{2207-987\sqrt{5}}{2})\\
16 = \alpha(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{20}+\beta(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{20} = \alpha(\frac{15127+6765\sqrt{5}}{2})+\beta(\frac{15127-6765\sqrt{5}}{2})\end{cases}$

Solving is tedious from this point on, but can be done.  Once you have calculated $\alpha$ and $\beta$, you can simply plug in whatever value of $x$ you like and finish the messy arithmetic to get a final answer.

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%2B1%29%3Df%28x%29%2Bf%28x-1%29,+f%2816%29%3D20,+f%2820%29%3D16) tells us that the final form of the equation can be simplified to $f(x)=19918L(x)-44538F(x)$ where $L(x)$ and $F(x)$ represent the $x^{th}$ Lucas and Fibonacci numbers respectively.

---

In the event that the equation was instead intended to be $f(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-1)$, rearranging gives us $f(x+1)=f(x)-f(x-1)$ and characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2=\lambda-1$.

This gives us solutions $\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$ and $\frac{1-\sqrt{3}}{2}$, well known numbers as they are the two primitive cube roots of negative one.

We expect our solution to be of the form $f(x)=\alpha\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right)^x + \beta\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}\right)^x$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$ to be determined from our initial conditions.

$\begin{cases}20 = \alpha(\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})^{16} + \beta(\frac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2})^{16}=\alpha(\frac{-1-\sqrt{-3}}{2}) + \beta(\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})\\
16 = \alpha(\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})^{20}+\beta(\frac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2})^{20} = \alpha(\frac{1-\sqrt{-3}}{2})+\beta(\frac{1+\sqrt{-3}}{2})  \end{cases}$

Solving will give you $\alpha=-2+6i\sqrt{3}$ and $\beta = \frac{4(\sqrt{3}-5i)}{\sqrt{3}+i}$

Plugging back into the equation, and plugging in your desired $x$ value, you can then find the value.  In particular $x=20162016$

Comment: This seems like a great answer but what's discouraging me is that this answer was expected to be gotten in 30 seconds.

Comment: If I wanted to race to try to find the answer, I would first recognize the recurrence type and see that it would cycle once every six, recognize that $20$ and $16$ are both not multiples of $3$ while $20162016$ is, and conclude that the value must be the same as for $f(18)$.  That being said, would I have thought to do that as a first instinct?  Probably not, but if I was training for a contest where this is a relevant problem type, it seems possible to get it within 30 seconds.

Comment: For completion sake, we would have $f(18)=f(19)+f(17)=f(20)+2f(18)+f(16)$ implying $f(18)=-f(20)-f(16)=-36$

Comment: @JMoravitz thank you for your answer, it was very clear, I just did not get where the characteristic polynomial came from, can you kindly suggest topics that I could read to understand where that came from?

Comment: @JMoravitz That sir, would be very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could make a table using the recurrence you've found with $f(x+1)=f(x)-f(x-1)$, and, after completing for $f(17),f(18),f(19)$, see that a recurrence arises.

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
x &16 &17 &18 &19 &20 &21 &22 &23 \\
\hline
f(x) &20 &-16 &-36 &-20 &16 &36 &20 &-16 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

If the question is as stated, the answer will have millions of digits because it is a Fibonacci-like series.
If the question is $f(x)=f(x+1)+f(x-1)$, then it repeats every six terms.

Comment: Can you explain why it has a period of 6 ?

Comment: What I got is -f(x-1) = f(x+2)

Comment: @WillJagy I am unfamiliar with the jargon you are using. Which area of Maths is it coming from ?

Comment: @user230452, from your equation it follows f(x-4)=-f(x-1)=f(x+2)

Comment: @Michael very good observation. I was feeling like it was just around the corner. Even so, I'd like to understand the theory behind this answer. What was that equation you were talking about and the sixth roots of unity doing here ?

Comment: @user230452, one usually first encounters $n^{th}$ roots of unity in either a course talking about complex numbers, or in an abstract algebra course.  See [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) on roots of unity.  In particular, he points out (as I did in my above answer), that in solving for the closed form, we know that it will be of the form $f(x)=\alpha \lambda_1^x + \beta \lambda_2^x$ with $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ being sixth roots of unity, which implies that the sequence is cyclic and necessarily repeats every six terms.

Comment: The theory behind where the equation $\lambda^2-\lambda+1=0$ comes from in this context can be seen from either linear algebra, or a branch of combinatorics dealing with recurrence relations.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks. I'll check it out. What we're doing is solving a recurrence relation using generating functions ?

Answer (score 0):

For $f(x) = f(x+1) + f(x-1)$, one can get (as was shown in the previous answer) the following characteristic equation $\lambda^2-\lambda +1 = 0$, which yields $\lambda_{1,2} = \frac{1\pm i\sqrt{3}}{2} = e^{\pm i \frac{\pi}{3}}$. Then the overall for the function is defined as

$f(x) = \alpha e^{ ix \frac{\pi}{3}} + \beta e^{ -ix \frac{\pi}{3}}$,

and using given conditions ($f(16) = 20$ and $f(20) = 16$) one can find $\alpha,\beta = -18\pm \frac{2i}{\sqrt{3}}$. Finally, plugging $x=20162016$, one will indeed find

$f(20162016) = -36$.

Comment: Under what topic can I learn about the workings of that characteristic equation?

Comment: I would start with functional equations.

Comment: Alright thanks!